# controlling versions in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

How to control versioning in asp.net projects?

We are a five member team and looks to use same solution file in asp.net.

I heard of using vss or tortoise svn..

how to use visual source safe  or tortoise svn tool or any other tools which has better performance for version controlling.. what are the requirements to set up version controlling.?

thank you

Comment: if you have the budget avoid VSS and consider Microsoft TFS. I used VSS, SVN, Mercurial and now TFS and the best of all in my opinion was Mercurial with TortoiseHg shell extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a HUGE question! It sounds like you are just learning the very basics of version control. You should start by understanding the basic concepts, then choosing a tool that is relatively easy to setup and learn.

Check out these other StackOverflow posts as a starting point:

[Learning Version Control, and learning it well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747/learning-version-control-and-learning-it-well)

[Learning version control with git first or via SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239477/learning-version-control-with-git-first-or-via-svn)

Comment: As a side note - that fact that you are developing ASP.Net shouldn't really make a difference to HOW you execute source control. The fact that you are thinking to use source control is great!!

Comment: you're right.this is the first i am going to use versioning..i will follow up your links.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do some test projects and try each system before you make a decision:

Do things like:

- Setup it up.
- Check out a file.
- Check in a file.
- Do a diff on two versions of a file.
- Rollback a file to an earlier version.

This is great work for an intern.  Once you start using source control, you'll wonder how you ever managed without it.